# How to display a html page in java using its source code?

Tags: java, html

I have a PageRead class and methods which will download the html source code from a given url.

```
public class PageRead {
public static StringBuilder readPage(String pageAddr) {
try {
URL url = new URL(pageAddr);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

String line;
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append(line+"\n");
}
reader.close();
return sb;            
} 

catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return new StringBuilder("");
}  

catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return new StringBuilder("");
}
}

public static void main(String arg[]){
System.out.println(readPage("http://www.google.com"));
}
}
```

This will return me the source code in a String soemthing like :

```
<!doctype html>.......</body></html>
```

Is there a way to display this html in something like a JFrame using this source code?

Comment: Swing components have very basic support for html, you may switch to JavaFx's  [WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can write source code to an file, something like: `File file = new File("index.html");` and than open that file with your default browser. Page open can be done with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html.

```
try {
    Files.write(file.toPath(), content.getBytes());
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(file.toURI());
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

If that is that what you think for :D

Answer (score 1):

You can have a simple browser in Java, if that was the question. There was a `JWebPane` until Java6, and now there is a WebKit-based engine as part of JavaFX:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BrowserTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        WebView view = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
        engine.load("http://www.google.com");
        root.getChildren().add(view);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Example was taken from a [gist](https://gist.github.com/skrb/2333689) of GitHub user skrb.
One thing I checked is that [`WebEngine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) also has [`loadContent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#loadContent-java.lang.String-) method where you can directly feed it with `HTML` content as a `String`, so you can write

```
engine.loadContent(readPage("http://www.google.com").toString());
```

in place of the current `load()` call (which takes an URL), just be prepared that the downloaded `HTML` code is not everything what a webpage needs.

Comment: hi I have tried your codes and it will work! But however I have added a JFrame class inside my java program, and I want to call this show browser method inside the JFrame, is it possible to do that? Right now i cant use the above codes inside the JFrame as JFrame extends JFrame class and does not allow me to extends Application class anymore!

Comment: @JasonWEI I have not tried that, but I think you will need this tutorial: [JavaFX for Swing Developers](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm)

Answer (score 0):

One can open a html page or content within a Swing's `JEditorPane`. `JEditorPane` has various constructors including:

```
JEditorPane(URL initialPage)
JEditorPane(String type, String text) // where type can be a MIME type: text/html
```

This can be used with simple html content; the limitation is the html version supported is 3.2 only. Optionally, the Swing application can open a `JavaFX`'s `WebView` within a `JFrame` using `JFXPanel`.